# How to get approximately value with differential

Tags: derivatives

I have a task where I know that $f(4)=2$ and $f'(4)=3$ and I have to get approximately  value of $f(3.99)$ with differential. Where do I even start? Do I have to find out what $f(x)$ is?
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

you can use first order Taylor-Lagrange formula which gives

$$f(a)\approx f(b)+(a-b)f'(b)$$

with $a=3.99$ and $b=??$.

Comment: Thank you, I got the answer 1.97, which is correct. It is odd that I see this formula for the first time - we never mentioned it on the lectures.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the definition of difference quotient:

$f(3,99)-f(4)\approx f^{'}(4)(3,99-4)$

$f(3,99)\approx f(4)+f^{'}(4)(3,99-4)$

Comment: Thank you, I got the correct answer.

Comment: This is only approximately true, of course; that should be $\approx$ not $=$.

Comment: Yes sure...I corrected it, thanks:-)